# How to get the color of a point on an object?

Tags: python, materials

I am new to blender coding, and I would like to get the color of a point on an object in python. I get the point on the object with `bpy.context.object.closest_point_on_mesh`. How would I get the color of the material at that specific point?

For example, if the point was at this empty, how would I get the greenish color on the monkey at that empty?

[image: Example]

Edit: I guess what I want to do is somehow find out what the output of the material would be if I inputted a single vector into all the vector inputs, like this picture below.

[image: What I want the material to look like, except I don't want it to actually look like this]

Except I don't want to edit the actual material. I just want to take some x, y, and z values, and see what the material would output.

It really seems like this problem should be extremely easy to solve. I doubt any of this even makes sense anyways. I have no clue how to even ask this question.